Favicon not show after deploy on Github Pages - Nuxt3
I have changed the default Nuxt favicon in the public folder. I kept the file name (favicon.ico). It's working locally, but after deployment, I have the default browser icon.
My nuxt.config.ts file:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        "@/assets/style/main.scss",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"
    ],
    vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    additionalData: '@use "@/assets/style/_colors.scss" as *;',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    modules: [
        '@nuxt/content',
        ['@nuxtjs/google-fonts', {
            families: {
                'Nunito': true,
                download: true,
                inject: true
            }
        }]
    ],
    app: {
        head: {
            title: 'My title'
        },
        baseURL: '/Portfolio/',
        buildAssetsDir: 'assets',
    },
    build: {
        transpile: [
            '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
            '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
            '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons',
            '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
            '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
        ]
    }
})


Have you tried to remove the cache of the website and open it on a private tab in your browser?

Yes, it didn't help

Try to host it on Netlify or Vercel?
